# JS : How can i convert the string ("Mar 10, 2015") to a Date object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string:

```
Mar 10, 2015
```

How can i convert this to a **Date** object in **JavaScript**?

I have seen examples of converting string of other types, but not in the above format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A string of that format can be converted to a date type using `new Date()`:

```js
var dateString = 'Mar 10, 2015';
var date = new Date(dateString);
alert(date)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just call `new Date(date_string)`

Example:

```
var dateString="Mar 10, 2015";
new Date(dateString)  // it will output Tue Mar 10 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (GTB Standard Time)
```

Comment: You can also use momentjs

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `new date` function

```
var dateString = 'Mar 10, 2015';
new Date(date_string)
```